# How to use ASP.Net and Bootstrap TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I'm using an ASP treeview on our Bootstrap website and having issues. I've already added an event so it will respond with a postback when a checkbox is clicked (as checkboxes are clicked other items on the treeview become available/not available). If I try and use the treeview within a Bootstrap page it's all badly formatted.

What can I do to make it format correctly (things don't line up correctly) using the ASP.Net treeview?

I'm using C# v4, ASP.Net and Bootstrap. I am not using MVC.

Thanks in advance.

Jeff.

Comment: Your facing an uphill battle, I would try this: https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

Comment: But how do I dynamically create it from code behind?

Comment: Unless you are "data binding" more than one treeview on your page, no need to create it in code behind. Just use regular html markup, create a `WebMethod` that returns json that your treeview can consume, or inject the json directly into the page.